Ducato intermittent exhaust smoke
2015 Fiat Ducato 2.3 Diesel. It's burning coolant, but only very intermittently. Sometimes I can drive without issue for hundreds of miles, sometimes it starts putting out clouds of white smoke after only ten miles. Switching the engine off for just a few minutes seems to fix it but often the smoke restarts a couple of miles later. Engine temp is fine until the coolant level drops. Radseal did nothing.
Is this a head gasket problem? DPF? Sensor? Or is there some other culprit? I have a friendly local garage but they haven't been able to reproduce.

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!
